# Quadratic equation calculator not working

Tags: c#

I would like some help with my code.
This is what I've done so far:

```
using System;

namespace quadratic_equcation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            float b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            float c = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            float D = b * b - 4 * (a * c);
            double dRoot = Math.Sqrt(D);
            double x1 = (-b + dRoot) / 2 * a;
            double x2 = (-b + dRoot) / 2 * a;


            Console.WriteLine("x1 = {0) x2 = {1}", x1, x2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything looks good. I got no errors but when I run it I get this error:

[image]

How can I fix it ?
And one more question. I couldn't use float with 'dRoot', 'x1' and 'x2' because I can't convert it from double to float.. How can i do this

Comment: You have a typo. Change {0) to {0} and it will work.

Comment: Also, make sure `D` is not negative before doing the square root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("x1 = {0) x2 = {1}", x1, x2);
```

you have a typo there... **{0)**
change it for

`Console.WriteLine("x1 = {0} x2 = {1}", x1, x2);`

PS: the roots signs are faulty too (one positive one negative)

```
double x1 = (-b + dRoot) / 2 * a;
double x2 = (-b - dRoot) / 2 * a;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have typo: **{0)** in format string.

```
Console.WriteLine("x1 = {0} x2 = {1}", x1, x2);
```

Moreover, you have error in algorithm: `x1` is same as `x2`.

```
double x1 = (-b + dRoot) / 2 * a;
double x2 = (-b - dRoot) / 2 * a;
```